# Flutter: Get FirebaseStorage Download URL & Upload Status

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm new to flutter. I am trying to get `StorageUploadTask` status and have the Download when is status `isCompleted` & `isSuccessful`. The examples I found online are of the old version:

```
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(avatarImageFile);
Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.future).downloadUrl;
```

The above doesn't work for the new `firebase_storage`plugin version. Please help. Below is my code so far.

```
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(avatarImageFile);

    StorageReference downRef = uploadTask.lastSnapshot.ref;
    String downloadUrl = await downRef.getDownloadURL();

    if(uploadTask.isComplete) {
      if(uploadTask.isSuccessful) {
        print('Upload Successful');
      } else if(uploadTask.isCanceled) {
        print('Upload Cancelled');
      } else {
        print('${uploadTask.lastSnapshot.error}');
      }
    } else if(uploadTask.isInProgress){
        print('Upload in Progress');
      } else if(uploadTask.isPaused) {
        print('Upload Paused');
      }
```

Comment: You need to Subscribe to uploadTask.event Stream to get the upload Status on Screen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Newer version:**

As the `.onComplete` has been removed, now you just need to await until the task is finished:

```dart
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images/foo.png');
await ref.putFile(fileToUpload);
String url = await ref.getDownloadURL(); // <-- This is your download url.
```

---

**Older version:**

The older version of plugin doesn't let you use `task.future()` anymore and in the documentation they say to use `lastSnapshot` which didn't work for me. So, I used `onComplete`. Here is the working solution:

```
var ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("your_path");
var uploadTask = ref.putFile(avatarImageFile);
var storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
var downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: this does  not seems to be working now, please provide the updated answer. there is nothing like onComplete

Comment: With the new version a simple await should do the trick on the trick: final Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance
         .ref().child("your_path");
await reference.putFile(fileToUpload);
return await reference.getDownloadURL();