# How to await the upload of file to Firebase Storage in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage in Flutter, using the following code.

```
StorageReference reference =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("$fileId.jpg");
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_imageFile);
```

This does seem to work. But I need to find a way, to await this upload process. How can I go about it, given that `reference.putFile(file)` doesn't return a future ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I eventually figured out the solution, it's mentioned here: [Flutter: Get FirebaseStorage Download URL & Upload Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707610/flutter-get-firebasestorage-download-url-upload-status/52714376#52714376)

As answered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad

we can use this:

```
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(avatarImageFile);
StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```