# Flutter : getDownloadUrl (firebase storage)

Tags: firebase, flutter, url, reference, firebase-storage

I have a problem with my flutter application. I want to upload an image to firebase storage and get the URL but the getDownloadUrl method doesn't work.
Here is my code :

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

...

Future<String> addImage(File file, firebase_storage.Reference reference) async{
  firebase_storage.UploadTask task = reference.putFile(file);
  firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot snapshot = task.snapshot;
  String urlString = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  return urlString;
}
```

I think it's because of the new version of firebase_storage(5.2.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for the firebase to store the image then only call getUrl by using await. Similarly, check out this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714376/5408464

```
   Future<String> addImage(File file, firebase_storage.Reference reference) async{
  final task = await reference.putFile(file);
  final urlString = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
  return urlString;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but the onComplete method is no longer available with the new firebase_storage version. How can I replace it?

Comment: @killian what do you mean?

Comment: It's not possible to use onComplete with "task" (because it's no longer available with the 5.2.0 version of firebase_storage). So is there an other way to wait for the firebase to store the image ? Without "onComplete"

Comment: Dart analysis: The getter 'onComplete isn't defined for the type 'UploadTask'.

Comment: @killian you dont need to use onComplete, just use await for it. Check our this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52714376/5408464.
and btw someone downvoted me for something they dont know kinda sad ;(

Comment: thank you its working now !! And I'm really sorry for that, I wanted to upvote your answer and no downvote but I can't do it now. Excuse me.. You saved my problem

Comment: @killian No problem, happy to help ;)

Answer (score -1):

We need to wait for the `UploadTask` to complete, as per the source code below:

```
Future<String> addImage(File file, firebase_storage.Reference reference) async{
  firebase_storage.UploadTask task = reference.putFile(file);
  String urlString = await (await task.whenComplete).ref.getDownloadURL().toString();
  await task.whenComplete(() async {
      urlString = await task.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }).catchError((onError) {
    print(onError);
  });
  return urlString;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but the onComplete method is no longer available with the new firebase_storage version. How can I replace it?

Comment: We could use the `whenComplete()` callback. I've updated the answer

Comment: wont work , ref , The getter 'ref' isn't defined for the type 'Future<TaskSnapshot> Function(FutureOr<dynamic> Function())'.